# suggestions on designing a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am designing a Jframe using netbeans. I do have few questions.

1. Can we create a label for a field in a desired location(For eg.,we have a field named height, I need to display a label below it indicating height is in cm) conditionally?
2. Can we disable a field based on a condition?(by disable I mean it shouldn't be displayed in my frame)

Can someone suggest me whether we can achieve them through some examples.

Tried this, after some helpful suggestions

```
 private void englishRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JLabel userlabel;
        if (englishRadioButton.isSelected())
                {
                    userlabel = new JLabel("Inches");
                    userlabel.setBounds(311, 59, 64, 36);
                    //userlabel.setLocation(307,55);
                    //userlabel.setSize(70,40);
                    userlabel.setForeground(Color.green);
                    userlabel.setText("Inches");
                    userlabel.setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println(englishRadioButton.getBounds());
                    inchesTextField.setVisible(true);
                }
    }
```

The textfield is visible only when I click the English radio button,at the same time I need to get a label but it's not displayed with the above code. Can I know where I am going wrong?

Please see the attached screenshots[image: When English button is clicked, I need a label beneath the second textfield as inches] [image: When Metric button is clicked,I am disabling the above text field]

When English button is clicked, I need a label beneath the second textfield as inches, I am disabling the text field when Metric is displayed. I am able to achieve the later one but not the former one

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, relative placement of components is easily achieved with use of layout managers.
2. Yes, all components have a `setEnabled(...)` and a `setVisible(...)` method either of which can be called at any time during a program's run. The former helps you activate/inactivate components and the latter helps make them visible/invisible. If you want to swap complete "views", use a CardLayout.

Regarding:

> Can someone suggest me whether we can achieve them through some examples.

Please, you first as I strongly believe that the onus of effort here should be yours, the questioner's, since you're the one asking the questions, and the one with the most to learn by coding as much as possible. Let's see your attempts and we can help you with them. Otherwise the best examples are to be found at the Swing Tutorials.

For links, please look here: [Swing Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> I tried the above posted code,conditionally disabling the text field works well but getting a label doesn't work. Can you please suggest on that?

I don't see you adding your JLabel to any component. If you are going to create a component on an event, you must add it to a component whose ancestor hierarchy eventually reaches a visible top-level component such as a JFrame. Then after adding a component to a container (say a JFrame), you must call `revalidate()` on the container to have its layout managers re-layout its components, and then `repaint()` to repaint any "dirty" pixels.

I again will re-iterate that you're far better off not using null layout and absolute positioning, but rather using layout managers and relative positioning. If you want a label with and without visible text, it's often best to add an empty JLabel to the GUI on GUI creation, and just set its text when needed, as long as the label is located somewhere that allows its text to shrink and expand.

Also, as to your current problem, you might wish to show a picture of what you're trying to achieve, and what you're getting. Or if you can't post a picture here yet, post a link to an image or images you've created, and then we'll post it for you.

Comment: I was able to conditionally disable a field using setVisible method. But I am unable to add a label to a text field conditionally. Tried like this created a new label object and set it's location and size using setLocation and setSize.But I don't see the label anywhere in the frame when I run my application.Can I know where I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Sandy: Best to avoid absolute positioning via setSize, setLocation or setBounds. Best to use layout managers to achieve best relative position so that your GUI works well on all platforms. For more specific help, please do create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check out the link), and then send me a comment to let me know it's done.

Comment: I tried the above posted code,conditionally disabling the text field works well but getting a label doesn't work. Can you please suggest on that?

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Attached the screenshots for reference of what's the issue.

Comment: @Sandy: thanks. will try to get back to it later in the day. Work responsibilities are taking over now.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I somehow managed to get that UI thing working. Till now what I did was I didn't include the labels in UI but was trying to enable and disable using the code(without actually designing them). As part of testing created them and now could change the labels,enable and disable the conditionally. Now,I need to start making the app working. Thank you very much for the inputs!!

Comment: @Sandy: very good. Glad you've got it working! Keep on learning!

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Is there any single method to clear the Jframe? like system.exit(0) for exiting the form?                         Right now I have to set all the text fields to a blank string when clear button is clicked viz.,heightTextField.setText("");

Comment: @Sandy: create an `ArrayList<JTextField>`, put all your text fields in this list, and in the clear button's ActionListener, iterate through the list, clearing your fields.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I made most of my application working except for a thing. I am trying to call a event inside another,don't know how to achieve. For instance in the screenshots shown above, I have code written in my clear Button. I want this method(clearbuttonActionPerformed) to call while I click a radio button(english or metric). Can I know how can this be achieved?

Comment: @Sandy: Create a common `clear()` method that does what you want. Call this method from within the clearbuttonActionPerformed method, and call it from within the radio button's ActionListener as well.

Comment: How to create a method inside a private method?                 private void clearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  clearmethod() }..How should I declare the clear method inside the above clearButtonActionPerformed method

Comment: @Sandy: wha? Who said anything about having a method inside of another method? You simply ***call*** the same method inside of the other two methods. All I'm recommending is simple common sense, something you should be able to figure out on your own.